# Python: Use Graph API to send mails with Outlook - Get token with microsoft username and password

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail, msal

I am trying to use the [office365](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#Working-with-Outlook-API) lybrary for Python to send mails with Outlook.
When I was working with SharePoint the authentication was very simple, as in the example below.

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential

sp_credentials = UserCredential(SHAREPOINT_USER,SHAREPOINT_PASSWORD)
sp_con = ClientContext(SHAREPOINT_SITE).with_credentials(sp_credentials)

files = sp_con.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(SHAREPOINT_PATH).files
sp_con.load(files).execute_query()
```

--> With the above I was able to see what files are in a SharePoint folder. But with the same connection I was able to delete, move or add files.

I just used the user credentials of my microsoft account and things worked.
However, for Outlook the office365 library uses MSAL for authentification.
The example given on the GitHub page is below.

```
import msal
from office365.graph_client import GraphClient

def acquire_token():
    """
    Acquire token via MSAL
    """
    authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id_or_name}'
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        authority=authority_url,
        client_id='{client_id}',
        client_credential='{client_secret}'
    )
    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
    return token


client = GraphClient(acquire_token)

client.me.send_mail(
    subject="Meet for lunch?",
    body="The new cafeteria is open.",
    to_recipients=["fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"]
).execute_query()
```

This example forces me to register an application with the Azure Active Directory because I need the Client ID of that application to create a `msal.ConfidentialClientApplication`. I don't want to do that.

Instead I look for an authentification method similar to the one I use for SharePoint.

Do you know of a way to get a token for `GraphClient()` that only requires me to provide username and password?

What I already tried:

The `msal.ConfidentialClientApplication` class has a function called [`acquire_token_by_username_password`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/msal/application.py#L1615). I replaced the `acquire_token_for_client` function with it but still face the problem that the `ConfidentialClientApplication` requires a Client ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples how to authenticate either with username and password or interactive authentication. If your user has enabled multi-factor authentication, then authentication with username and password won't work.

Username and password authentication:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/username_password_sample.py

Interactive authentication:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/interactive_sample.py

Comment: Thank you :)
Gonna check and approve if it leads to success.

Comment: Your examples all require a client ID. I am looking for a method that works without a client ID.

Comment: client id is always required. It's a reference to an app and permissions are tied to that app. Try to ask directly in GitHub [repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues)

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. MSAL always needs the application. If you adapt your answer to something like "No, MSAL always needs a Client ID. It's stated in the documentation here: Link" I will reward your effort by accepting your answer. Otherwise I will answr the question myself.